# Photoshop PNG problem

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

I'm trying to use a PNG but when I open it in Photoshop it looks wrong.

[This is the original image](http://monmusu.tv/character/img/chara0.png)

[This is how it looks in Photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgC7w.png)

Any idea of how to make it look right?

Comment: Not that it helps your case but It opens fine for me in Photoshop CC15.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the layer is "index", that means that the image now is in the indexed color mode, you should switch it to RGB mode.

So go to Image -> Mode -> RGB color.

Or else, try opening the PNG as a smart object (File -> Open as Smart Object) , and see if it'll be in RGB color mode.

I hope that this'll help you.

Comment: No, already tried that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I found a solution, I used pixlr.com to re-save the image, apparently the PNG is using indexed colors and an alpha palette rather than using a full alpha mask